# Highcharts - Starting index of series at 1 instead of 0

Tags: highcharts

I've put a label in my data showing the index of each serie:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{series.index}'
                }
            }
            },
```

Altough it starts at 0 and I would like it to start at 1.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8151nkk/) a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch from `format` to `formatter` to easily solve this. It provides more flexibility and advanced functionality. The `format` attribute can only do simple tasks involving the variables in their original form.

You have:

```
format: '{series.index}'
```

Replace it with:

```
formatter: function() {
    return this.series.index+1;
}
```

As in [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/g8151nkk/1/).